# How can I connect from a container to a service on the host's localhost?

Tags: docker

According to Docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

I should be able to use `host.docker.internal`. However, if I follow the example I get the following  error:

```
/ # curl http://host.docker.internal:8000
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: host.docker.internal
```

Comment: What version of Docker are you using? `host.docker.internal` [does not exist in all versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach).

Comment: And what platform are you running on? If you're using Linux you need to explicitly enable the `host.docker.internal` address.